# Getting the failed-assert from the sch file

Tags: schema, xslt-2.0, saxon, schematron, oxygenxml

I have an .sch file provided by PEPPOL website: http://docs.peppol.eu/poacc/billing/3.0/files/PEPPOL-EN16931-UBL.sch and we need to convert it to .xsl. We have done the conversion using a tool called oXygen.

This is the snipped from .sch that generates the [BR-S-06]

```
<rule context="cac:AllowanceCharge[cbc:ChargeIndicator=false()]/cac:TaxCategory[normalize-space(cbc:ID)='S'][cac:TaxScheme/normalize-space(upper-case(cbc:ID))='VAT']">
      <assert id="BR-S-06" flag="fatal" test="(cbc:Percent) > 0">[BR-S-06]-In a Document level allowance (BG-20) where the Document level allowance VAT category code (BT-95) is "Standard rated" the Document level allowance VAT rate (BT-96) shall be greater than zero.</assert>
    </rule>
```

This is how I am expecting a rule to show as:

```
<!--ASSERT -->
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@listID = 'UNCL1001'"/>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <svrl:failed-assert xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" test="@listID = 'BR-S-06'">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">BR-S-06</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="flag">fatal</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="location">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <svrl:text>[BR-S-06]-In a Document level allowance (BG-20) where the Document level allowance VAT category code (BT-95) is "Standard rated" the Document level allowance VAT rate (BT-96) shall be greater than zero.</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" mode="M7"/>
```

This is how it is actually shown:

```
    <!--ASSERT -->
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="(cbc:Percent) &gt; 0"/>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
           <xsl:text>[BR-S-06]-In a Document level allowance (BG-20) where the Document level allowance VAT category code (BT-95) is "Standard rated" the Document level allowance VAT rate (BT-96) shall be greater than zero.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:message>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="M10"/>
```

I am expecting to see the failed-assert element because it also contains the id/flag/location rather then what i currently get which is a message.

To run the validation using Saxon we have the following code:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>> ValidateXML(string xslTemplate, string xslName, XmlDocument document)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>> resultToReturn = new Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>>();

            XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespacesForDocument = GetAllNamespaces(document);
            var transformAssertFailed = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var processor = new Processor();
            var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();
            var executable = compiler.Compile(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xslTemplate)));
            var destination = new DomDestination();

            MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
            document.Save(xmlStream);
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            using (xmlStream)
            {
                var transformer = executable.Load();

                transformer.SetInputStream(xmlStream, new Uri("file:///C:/"));
                transformer.Run(destination);
            }
            return resultToReturn;
        }
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, maybe the .sch file that I started with or maybe the .sch to .xsl converter.

Comment: There is more than one Schematron processor written in XSLT (that is, a set of stylesheets that converts a Schematron schema to a set of XSLT rules). You don't tell us anything about which Schematron processor you are using. Perhaps your expected output is based on one, and your actual output on another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question on the oXygen form [here](https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic20377.html) and I got my question answered.